# WebVTT: Escape &amp; in subtitle for Firefox 87.0

Tags: webvtt, vtt

I'd like to generate Web VTT subtitle files for a video about HTML.

But I can't figure out how to show the string `&amp;` in Firefox. This works fine in Chromium 89.0 (it shows `&amp;`):

```
00:00.000 --> 00:02.000
&amp;amp;
```

But Firefox 87.0 shows just `&`.

Comment: maybe &amp;&nbsp;amp; works? Otherwise i think it is in bug in firefox?

Comment: Interesting idea. The result is this: Firefox and Chromium both show `&amp;&nbsp;amp;` as `& amp;`. With a visible space in between. So remove this visible space I also tried `&shy;` as invisible control character. The result is this: Firefox shows `&amp;&shy;amp;` as `&&shy;amp;`, Chromium shows this as `&amp;`. >> I will create an issue at Firefox.

Comment: Bugzilla-Ticket: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1704099